# Should I make my REST API a PUT or POST for a file upload?

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I am working on an API that will take an xml file, parse the file to a DTO and return the results in the form of JSON. Technically you can say the API's purpose is to only parse the file and return the results in a "nice" format. I'm not sure whether or not it makes more sense to make this a POST vs PUT api? I know POST is usually for create and PUT is for update. In this case I'm not really creating or updating anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't doing something standard, [it's okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `PUT` is to *replace* what exists at your target url.

So if you do a PUT request with a file on `/foo/bar`, then I would expect a `GET` request afterwards on `/foo/bar` to return that same file.

It doesn't sound like that's what you're doing, so `POST` is likely the right choice.